# Why do I see more threads at OS level than are spawned by my code?

Tags: python, multithreading

Python programs generates threads on some conditions with the following code:

```
thread1 = threading.Thread(target=foo, args=(arg1,))
thread1.start()
```

The problem is that I see too many threads at OS level:

```
$ ps -efL | grep myscript.py | wc -l
4117
```

However, in the program, with `threading.enumerate()` or `threading.active_count()`, the thread count is just 200.

What are the remaining threads? Are they inactive? Is there a way to check the function name of those 4000+ threads?

Comment: You might not be counting what you think you're counting.  What does `ps -e -o pid,command,thcount | grep myscript[.]py` show?

Comment: Well, OS thread count is right..it does show..    ps -e -o pid,command,thcount  does show the 4117 in this case..

Answer (score 0):

It is weird, but there is posibility that those 4000 threads are all threads from your PC, for example right now i have 3840 active Threads, and python should not give you all tasks from your pc. In python if you have only MainThread you should see 1 after typing `threading.active_count()`, or more if you create and start other tasks. You cant see all threads name, you can see only those which are related to your python program. Typing:

```
for x in threading.enumerate():
    print(x.getName())
```

Will show you all threads in this session with their name

Comment: threading.enumerate() just shows 200 threads only..